# <f:ajax> does not render at all

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

This is my Facelet:

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{managedBean.runner.postnr}" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" onevent="blur" render="output" />
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{managedBean.placeFromPostNR}"/>
```

I'm trying to autoupdate outputText with a value from `managedBean.placeFromPostNR`when the user exit's the `inputText`. But this does not work at all.

Here's my `managedBean.placeFromPostNR` code:

```
public String getPlaceFromPostNR(){
    return db.getPlaceFromPostNR(runner.getPostnr());
}
```

This method is never invoked, have some printlines as test.

I've even tried with setting `<h:outputText id="output" value="#{managedBean.runner.postnr}"/>` and setting `onevent="keyup"` to check if my methods which gives the error. But this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onevent` attribute is invalid. It [should](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) be `event`.

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur" render="output" />
```